# best way to kill Android app in onPerformSync() (SyncAdapter)

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have a SyncAdapter extending AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter . I want to clear cache (no problem) and kill the app in onPerformSync(), what would be the best way to kill the app in onPerformSync() ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to finish all Activities gracefully, and do this by calling finish() for all activities that haven't been destroyed already.

I answered a question earlier today similar to this in order to finish all activities still not ended in a user's application:

[OnBackPressed after implementation taking me back to a previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362198/onbackpressed-after-implementation-taking-me-back-to-a-previous-activity/32362362#32362362)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In onPerformSync(), is there a way to find all active activities of the current app? I only have application text and not sure how to find all active activities from it. Thanks.